# Startup NOMOUNT and Startup MOUNT on dataguard oracle

Tags: oracle-10g, dataguard

I have a question here about Oracle data guard.

After performing a switchover, we shutdown the new standby database and startup it.
At this stage, sometimes I find DBA performance in 2 different steps:

1. `startup mount;`
2. `startup nomount;` then 
   `alter database mount standby database;`

What's the difference between above commands? Could somebody tell me?

Thanks for helping me and forgive me about my English writing.

Comment: Have you read http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/starting_database.htm already?

Comment: yes i read it before. but whats relation with data guard environment?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1004.htm#i2079759):

> ***`startup_clauses`***
>
> The *`startup_clauses`* let you mount and open the database so that it is accessible to users.
>
> **`MOUNT` Clause**
>
> Use the `MOUNT` clause to mount the database. Do not use this clause when the database is already mounted.
>
> **`MOUNT STANDBY DATABASE`**
>
> You can specify `MOUNT STANDBY DATABASE` to mount a physical standby database. The keywords `STANDBY DATABASE` are optional, because Oracle Database determines automatically whether the database to be mounted is a primary or standby database. As soon as this statement executes, the standby instance can receive redo data from the primary instance.

`startup mount` is the same as `startup nomount; alter database mount`.

So there is no practical difference between the two approaches you showed, if the commands are run consecutively (i.e. you are not doing anything else while it is started but not mounted). However, including `STANDBY DATABASE` in the command clearly shows intent, so I think it's generally better to include it, particularly if you're scripting this as part of a switchover process.

Comment: are you sure there is no practical difference between these two?

Comment: @DevYudh - pretty sure; it [goes through these stages on a normal startup](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e25789/startup.htm#BABDBBAJ). Is there a reason you think there is a difference?

Answer (score 0):

**Startup mount**: This command is Useful to bring the database into the mount state.This mode is Useful for recovery of the database. in this mode only dba can access full database.

**Startup nomount**: This command is Useful for two purpose.
1:To create A New database
2:To create new control file to the existing database

Anyways in your scenario, both approaches are same.